# Combine 2 JSON Objects Without Array

Tags: java, arrays, json, gson

I wish to get the JSON output as below which is two objects combined I think without using array. How can I get the following output?

```
{
    "AppData": {
        "status": "****",
        "message": [
            ""
        ]
    },
    "Data": {
        "token": "****"
    }
}
```

I try the array way and if I get rid of the "[" and "]" then it will become invalid JSON.

My code as follows

```
public Response getSAppData(int id, String email, String password){
    Map<String, AppData> AppDataHM = new HashMap<String, AppData>(); 
    Map<String, Data> DataHM1 = new HashMap<String, Data>();

    Data data = DataHM.get(new AppDataRequest (id, email, password));
    List<String> message = new ArrayList<>();

    message.add("");
    AppDataHM.put("AppData", new AppData("success", message));
    DataHM1.put("Data", data);
    String AppDataJO = new Gson().toJson(AppDataHM);
    String DataJO = new Gson().toJson(DataHM1);
    String ADJODJOA = "["+AppDataJO+","+DataJO+"]"; 
    return Response.status(200).entity(ADJODJOA).build();
}
```

And the output of my code as below

```
[
  {
    "AppData": {
      "status": "success",
      "message": [
        ""
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "Data": {
      "token": "token1"
    }
  }
]
```

Thank in advance for any reply and answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All. I find a solution by first combining the two HashMap into one then only convert it to object.
Below is my code.

```
Map<String, AppData> AppDataHM = new HashMap<String, AppData>(); 
Map<String, Data> DataHM1 = new HashMap<String, Data>();

Map ADHMDHM = new HashMap<>();

Data data = DataHM.get(new AppDataRequest (id, email, password));
List<String> message = new ArrayList<>();

message.add("");
AppDataHM.put("AppData", new AppData("success", message));
DataHM1.put("Data", data);
ADHMDHM.putAll(AppDataHM);
ADHMDHM.putAll(DataHM1);
String ADHMDHM1 = new Gson().toJson(ADHMDHM);
```